# Kinetic Equation of Gas: Why is $T$ not the time of impact?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, physical-chemistry, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, gas

so i just learnt about about the derivation of Kinetic Gas Equation! In that derivation, and i have a question which i am trying to find the answer for but i can't find it anywhere on the internet!

In the derivation when we are deriving the formula for force on a particle, we first find that change in momentum after hitting a face is -2mv.

In order to find the force on a particle, we first take change in momentum and then divide by the time of impact.

But in the derivation, we take the time of impact as the time it takes for a particle to travel all the way across the container and then come back and collide with the same face again.

But time of impact logically should be the time for which the particle is in contact with the face, as when the particle travels through the entire length of the container (after it is has collided for the first time) remains constant and there is no force on the particle of the ideal gas.I simply am not able to understand as to why the time of impact considered that way! I appreciate every answer. [image]

[image: Derivation]

Answer (score 3):

We are not interested in the force just while the molecule is in contact with the wall, but with the *mean* force all the time that the molecule is banging backward and forwards. Therefore we divide the molecule's change in momentum on hitting a wall by the time between one mid-collision with the wall and the next mid-collision.

You might care to think of a graph of force against time for the molecule hitting the wall. The graph will consist of a series of regularly-spaced narrow spikes. The area under each is $\Delta p$. The *mean* force will be a low-down horizontal line on the graph, the area under which for a given time interval is the same as the sum of areas under the spikes for the same time interval.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

But this $t$ is not called "time of impact" or the "mean free time of the particle". The derivation is correct and you could just use the mean time between collisions ($\tau$) as $\tau=\frac{t}{2}$ if you prefer it. If you do so, $F=\frac{\Delta p}{2\tau}$ and $\tau=\frac{l}{V_x}$.

Comment: Noted! Thanks for your answer!