# $U = (3/2)nRT$ proof on Khan Academy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, collision, ideal-gas

I’m in the middle of the thermodynamics unit with my AP Physics 2 students and I’m attempting to understand how the expression for total internal energy of an ideal gas is derived.

I’ve taught for 15 years, so I readily understand the simplification of internal energy of an ideal gas in not accounting for rotational/vibrational kinetic energies or any forms of energy other than the kinetic energy of the particles.

On YouTube, there is a video from khan academy [seen here](https://youtu.be/qSFY7GKhSRs?si=TCA11jOrodE9AKk5) that attempts to derive the expression for internal energy of an ideal gas as $U=(3/2)nRT$. At about the 7 minute mark, the video describes the time duration for the momentum change and I can’t over (under?) the fact that the “time” used when determining force as the rate of change in momentum is chosen to be the time it takes the particle to traverse the length of the cube…

The change in momentum that’s being referenced ($-2mv$) occurs during the time it takes from when the particle first makes contact with the wall to when it last makes contact with the wall and leaves in the opposite direction, i.e. the during the impulse $J=F•t…$ shouldn’t THAT be the time used instead of the length of the cube divided by the speed of the particle?? Clearly, the end result matches what we know to be the case but, man, can anyone point out where my logic is failing?

Comment: See the answer to this previous question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/570485/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kinetic Equation of Gas: Why is $T$ not the time of impact?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/570485/)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think the explanation given is a little misleading. But we can obtain the same formula by looking at the problem in a slightly different way.

We need to consider that, out of the $ \frac{N}{3} $ molecules that is supposedly taken to be travelling in the direction perpendicular to the wall, not all of them are in the process of collision at any given instant, some fraction of particles are travelling between the walls. Therefore it is important to consider the collision rates of the particles which tells us that how many particles are in contact with walls on an average.

Since a particle travelling perpendicular to the wall travels twice the length of the box (L) before the second collision, its collision rate is $$ \frac{1}{(\frac{2L}{v})} $$ where v is the speed of the particle.

The momentum transferred to the wall at any instant is therefore equal to total collision rate multiplied by the momentum transferred by each collision $$ (\text{Number of particles travelling in the direction} \times \text{Rate of collision}) \times (\text{momentum transferred by each collision}) $$

which is equal to,
$$ \frac{N}{3} \times\frac{1}{(\frac{2L}{v})} \times   
\text{2mv} $$
This gives us the required expression for force on the wall at any given time.